# How to apply rolling updates in VM instances instead of using Managed Instance group in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

**Problem**: I want to apply patch updates in a `VM instance` which is **not a part** of a `Managed Instance Group`. The patch update could be-

1. A change in the version of the current OS of a VM instance, that is, `change from Ubuntu-16-v1 to Ubuntu-16-v2`.
2. An upgrade of the OS boot, that is, `changing from Ubuntu-16 OS to Ubuntu-18 OS`.
3. Installation of a new package in the existing machine.

**Exploration**:

- For Problem 1 & 2 stated above

> I have explored and tried the rolling update feature present in Managed Instance Group in the `Google Cloud Platform` and this seems to be a good approach for the problem stated, but what should be the best approach with best practices if someone is not using a Managed Instance Group? You may find the details [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/upgrading-images-in-migs).

- For Problem 3 stated above

> I have tried the [`Os-patch Management`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-patch-management) service of GCP but is there any other method that I could use?

Answer (score 1):

Create an "image" from the boot disks of your existing Compute Engine instances.
For updating with newer configurations and software, group images in "image family" which always points to the latest image.
See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#setting_families

Comment: The thing that you are referring to is Image Versioning, right? But what I am asking is "How to update the current Machine with the new version of Image". Say Today a VM was created with ubuntu-v1 and tomorrow google has updated their Image to ubuntu-v2. Then how should I apply this new image to an existing instance preserving the startup scripts, metadata, network configurations, etc.

Comment: I think you should manage your use case using IAC like terraform so that VMs can be destroyed and recreated again using updated IMAGE from the same disk, internal IP, etc. Either schedule auto-update or provide self-update instructions for VM owners

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, I think you should use IAC script like terraform to recreate similar VMs with the same name, disk, internal address, etc..and call the script from the repo directly on a scheduled date automatically or provide self patch instructions.

Here is the likely process:

- Send Email Notification to all the VM owners that Auto-Patch is
  scheduled on XYZ.
- Email content should include an Instance list going to be
  patched/update, list of action, patch team contact details.
- An email should also include a link for skipping this auto-update and perform "Self Patching instruction"
  documents
- Self patching documents should have a command to call autopatch
  wrapper script like: "curl -u "encrypted-auth:x-oauth-basic" -k -H 'Accept:
  application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw' 
  'https://github.com/api/v3/repos/xyz/images/contents/gcp/patch_OS_update.sh?ref=master'
  |bash -s -- -q"

The above script can also have other options like to query patchset available for particular VM or scan the VM for pending updates